# CharacterIterator with switch statement and if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

i tryed an CharacterIterator and the Switch Statement works fine just if i try to add a If statement within the case for i it shows me nothing. Could you tell me where my mistake is?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
CharacterIterator it= new StringCharacterIterator(input);{
for(char ch = it.first(); ch!= CharacterIterator.DONE; ch = it.next()) {
    switch(ch) {
    case 'E':
        sb.append("S");
        break;
    case 'n':
        sb.append("O");
        break;
    case 'g':
        sb.append("L");
        break;
    case 'a':
        sb.append(".");
        break;
    case 'i':
        if(it.previous() == ' ') {
            sb.append("ai");
            break;
        }
        break;
    case ' ':
        sb.append(" ");
        break;
    } } }
```

There is my code. The output of "Engine" should be "SOLai" and i try to check if character "i" is in the beginning of the word or some where else. So that if its in the beginning my output will replace the "i" with an "ai" and if its not it should delete it.

Comment: Each time you call `it.previous()`, you are undoing the `it.next()` that would allow your loop to progress.  So once you encounter the letter `i`, your program keeps encountering that same `i` over and over.

Comment: Thanks for explainig the problem didnt see that issue! Do you also know how to move on after i checked the previous character? i tryed to add a it.next() but it didnt worked @VGR

Comment: `it.next()` will indeed work, but it needs to be after your `if` block, because you are calling it.previous() every time 'i' is encountered, regardless of whether or not the if-test passes.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
CharacterIterator it= new StringCharacterIterator(input);{
for(char ch = it.first(); ch!= CharacterIterator.DONE; ch = it.next()) {
    switch(ch) {
    case 'E':
        sb.append("S");
        break;
    case 'n':
        sb.append("O");
        break;
    case 'g':
        sb.append("L");
        break;
    case 'a':
        sb.append(".");
        break;
    case 'i':
        if(it.previous() == ' ') {
            sb.append("ai");
            it.next();
            break;
        }
        sb.append("I");
        it.next();
        break;
    case ' ':
        sb.append(" ");
        break;
    } } 
System.out.print(sb.toString());
}
```

You need to add the **it.next()** in the **if statement and after** that the for **loop will move on** to the next character! Thanks to @VGR